# How to find the following limit? $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am facing challenges with such type of limits.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$$

I tried to search on the internet but couldn't find a solution

Comment: no, i didnt know

Comment: This question is sort of a red herring. The function is not defined when $x=0$ or $y=0$. Exempting the origin is not good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$. This is a continuous function everywhere except $x=0$, where the limit exists and is $1$. Thus, if we also define $f(0)=1$, we have a continuous function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Thus $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(xy)=f\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}xy\right)=f(0)=1.$$

**Edit:** As pointed out by Ted Shifrin, this function is not defined in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ because it is undefined on the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$. Thus this becomes a definitional issue - some definitions require the function to be defined for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, others only require it to be close to the putative limit on its points of definition. Under the first interpretation, this limit does not exist, and under the second interpretation, it is $1$ because $\frac{\sin x}x=f(x)$ whenever it is defined, and $f(xy)$ does indeed have limit $1$.

Comment: There seems to be a more significant problem here. The function is not defined on the lines $x=0$, $y=0$, so the limit really does not exist.

Comment: @Ted Sorry, took me a bit to write up my response. Better?

Comment: @Ted It is worthwhile to note that this subtle point has not been caught in other similar questions, e.g. [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323743/how-to-find-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-sinx-cdot-yx?rq=1)

Comment: We can obviously define f (xy) = 1 if xy = 0, and f (xy) = sin (xy) / (xy) otherwise, and the limit becomes 1. As long as we stay aware that the original function has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

draw a graph of a sector of circle with centre $O$, centre angle $x$.

we will find that: $$\sin(x)<x \implies \sin(x)/x < 1$$ and $$x < \tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$$

then we have $$\cos(x) < \sin(x)/x < 1.$$

By squeeze theorem,  $\lim \sin(x)/x =1$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$.

Comment: we will find that: sin(x) < x

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the denominator, you can write: $\sin(xy) = xy - \dfrac{(xy)^3}{3!} + \dfrac{(xy)^5}{5!} -....+$, and divide both sides by $xy$ to get:
$\dfrac{\sin(xy)}{xy} = 1 + o((xy)^2)$, from this you get the limit is $1$.