# Multivariable limits: $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x y)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x y)}{x}$ if $x\neq0$

$f(0,y) = 0$

Find the limit at $(0,0)$ if it exists, or prove the limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: Hey Alicia, could you please show your efforts? This appears to be a homework problem.

Comment: Here exactly same https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323743/how-to-find-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-sinx-cdot-yx/323753#323753

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x\cdot y)}{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323743/how-to-find-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-sinx-cdot-yx)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy by Tayler series solving.
Now proof by limit of two variables
$ \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(xy)} {x} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(xy)} {x} =0 $

Answer (score 0):

We have to consider $x\neq0$ and look at how does the mapping behaves in this case. We have to approach the point $(0,0)$. We have two different cases.

If $y=0$ then the mapping is identically $0$, thus the limit is $0$ as $x\to0$.

Otherwise $y\neq0$; in this case we write
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin xy}{x}
=y\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin xy}{xy}=y
$$
which goes to $0$ as $y\to0$.

So the limit exists and it is $0$. Notice in particular the mapping is continuous on the line $x=0$.